# Small Edit on Import Range Script for Mass Edits on Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I found a [great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZtb3lRWn74) on YouTube about editing Google Sheets in bulk, however the script writes over formulas with cell values.  I'd like to have formulas be edited from the master sheet rather than writing over with cell values.  Is this possible?

Script:

```
function getdata() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER ID HERE").getFiles()
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      var shoot = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());

      var sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("SHEET NAME HERE");
      var sourcerange = sourcesheet.getRange('RANGE HERE');
      var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues();

    var destsheet = shoot.getSheetByName('SHEET NAME HERE'); 
    var destrange = destsheet.getRange('RANGE HERE'); 
destrange.setValues(sourcevalues);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Instead of setValues(sourcevalues) you could use [setFormulas(formulas)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasformulas)