# Equivalent of IMPORTRANGE with script in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, google-sheets-query, importrange

Since the `Importrange()` is not working as expected, do you know how I could express e.g the following function with a script?

```
={IMPORTRANGE("SheetKey","SheetName1!A:J") ; 
  IMPORTRANGE("SheetKey","SheetName2!A2:J") ; 
  IMPORTRANGE("SheetKey","SheetName3!A2:J")}
```

Comment: I bet I can fix it for you if you can share a copy of your sheets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Small Edit on Import Range Script for Mass Edits on Google Spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/99164/small-edit-on-import-range-script-for-mass-edits-on-google-spreadsheets)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tEBP-4mrGSIZcYcHWltmzcgM4Ro_TzZgt1xjxGZhz3E/edit#gid=2133726147 Here is a sample dataset with read access. Let me know if it helps, thanks @user0

Comment: You will have to explain *not working as expected* in your question; tell us the expected versus actual results. Also, [edit] that last comment into your question. Questions on SE sites should contain all essential information. Comments can disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=QUERY({'AW Data'!A1:J; 'Facebook Data'!A1:J; 'Bing Data'!A1:J}, "where Col1 is not null")
```

[image: 0]